# Divide each value in list array

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to divide by 80 of each array value in the list. What I have tried is,

```
dfs = pd.read_excel('ff1.xlsx', sheet_name=None)
dfs1 = {i:x.groupby(pd.to_datetime(x['date']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))['duration'].sum() for i, x in dfs.items()}
d = pd.concat(dfs1).groupby(level=1).apply(list).to_dict()
print(d)
```

OP :

```
{'2017-05-06': [197, 250], '2017-05-07': [188, 80], '2017-05-08': [138, 138], '2017-05-09': [216, 222], '2017-06-09': [6]}
```

But Expected OP :

```
1 : Divide by 80
{'2017-05-06': [2, 3], '2017-05-07': [2, 1], '2017-05-08': [2, 2], '2017-05-09': [2, 2], '2017-06-09': [0]}
2 : total of each array and subtract each value (3+2 = 5-3 and 5-2)
{'2017-05-06': [3, 2], '2017-05-07': [1, 2], '2017-05-08': [2, 2], '2017-05-09': [2, 2], '2017-06-09': [0]}
```

How to do this using python?

Comment: Can you post `dfs.head().to_dict()` please?

Comment: @jpp  dfs.head().to_dict()
AttributeError: 'collections.OrderedDict' object has no attribute 'head'

Comment: @jpp - It is dictionary of DataFrames.

Comment: @jpp - `sheet_name=None` return from all sheets dictinaories of DataFrames

Comment: Rule 2) of yours can be simplified to *reversing* the array if it is always of  size 2

Answer (score 3):

I think need:

```
d = pd.concat(dfs1).div(80).astype(int)
d = d.groupby(level=1).transform('sum').sub(d).groupby(level=1).apply(list).to_dict()
print (d)

{'2017-06-09': [0], '2017-05-08': [1, 1], '2017-05-09': [2, 2], 
 '2017-05-07': [1, 2], '2017-05-06': [3, 2]}
```

**Explanation**:

1. First create `MultiIndex` DataFrame by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html)
2. Divide by [`div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.div.html) and if necessary convert to `int`s
3. For sum per groups use [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for possible subtract values by [`sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sub.html)
4. Last create `list`s with [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html)

Comment: when there is single value like '2017-06-09': [6] then its display '2017-06-09': [0] instead of '2017-06-09': [6]

Comment: @MMMMS - beacuse sum of `[6]` is `6` and after subtract `6-6=0`. There is difference?

Comment: i understand. but i want [6] then 6-0 =6.

Comment: @MMMMS I just check it and it is a bit different - `0` is because `int(6/80)` is `0`, then `0-0=0`

Comment: No... after d = pd.concat(dfs1).div(80).astype(int) the OP is {'2017-06-09': [6]} which means [555/80] = [6]. so final OP should be [6 - 0] =[6]

Comment: @MMMMS - OK, so if length of list is `1` then is no subtract? If another value `{'2018-10-19': [2]} ` from `[160/80] = [2]` then output is too `[2]`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167453/discussion-between-mmmms-and-jezrael).